# CakePHP file upload on 000webhost

Tags: php, cakephp, file-upload, shared-hosting

I am trying to get my app to be able to handle uploads. This is the add action in DealsController.php.

```
<?php
        public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->request->data['Deal']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
            $this->Deal->create();
            if ($this->Deal->uploadFile($this->request->data['Deal']['pic'])){
                $file = $this->request->data['Deal']['pic'];
                $this->request->data['Deal']['pic'] = $this->request->data['Deal']['pic']['name'];
                if ($this->Deal->save($this->request->data)) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your deal has been saved. %s', h(serialize($file)) ));
                    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                }
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add your deal. %s', h(serialize($file)) ));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to upload the file. Please try again. %s', h(serialize($this->request->data['Deal']['pic']))));
        }
    }
```

The `uploadFile` function is defined in the model in Deal.php

```
<?php
public function uploadFile( $check ) {

    $uploadData = array_shift($check);

    if ( $uploadData['size'] == 0 || $uploadData['error'] !== 0) {
        return false;
    }

    $uploadFolder = 'files'. DS .'your_directory';
    $fileName = time() . '.pdf';
    $uploadPath =  $uploadFolder . DS . $fileName;

    if( !file_exists($uploadFolder) ){
        mkdir($uploadFolder);
    }

    if (move_uploaded_file($uploadData['tmp_name'], $uploadPath)) {
        $this->set('pic', $fileName);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

`uploadFile` keeps returning false and I get my
```

> Unable to upload the file. Please try again.
>   a:5:{s:4:"name";s:7:"012.PDF";s:4:"type";s:15:"application/pdf";s:8:"tmp_name";s:14:"/tmp/phpw0uVGS";s:5:"error";i:0;s:4:"size";i:70118;}

flash. Which is confusing, since it makes it look like the file was actually uploaded to a temp dir. I tried different paths for `move_uploaded_file` but nothing worked. Does this have something to do with file permissions? It couldn't be file-size, since my upload file was only about 80 KB.

Comment: do the upload path have proper permission set? a 755 would be good enough.

Comment: would I need to have the chmod set on the entire chain of folders, or would it suffice to set the target subfolder to 775?

Comment: only the folder you are uploading file to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: Don't try to code it yourself. Use one of the already existing file upload plugins for CakePHP, which will handle all the ins and outs behind the scenes, with minimal coding on your part.

I personally use https://github.com/josegonzalez/upload